# Некорректный вывод после чтения файла C++

Tags: c++, текст

Добрый день! У меня имеется статический метод `listOfStudents()` который открывает текстовый файл и считывает оттуда мои данные...

Мой текстовый файл выглядит вот так:

[image: Текстовый файл]

Как вы можете видеть на картинке простой текстовый файл с данными.

Моя задача это взять оттуда **Имя** и **Фамилию** и вывести на экран:

Полноценно мой метод выглядит вот так:

```
static void listStudents(){
    cout << endl << "List students" << endl<< endl;
    ifstream textfile;
    string line;
    string unused = "";
    textfile.open("students.txt");
    if(textfile.is_open()){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 , j = 0; !textfile.eof(); i++){
                if(i == j){
                    count++;
                    textfile >> line;
                    cout << count << ": " << line;
                    textfile >> line;
                    cout << " " << line << endl;
                    j+=11;
                }else{
                    textfile >> unused;
                    unused = "";
                }
        }
    }else{
        cout << "You don't have any students!" << endl;
    }
    textfile.close();
    cout << endl << endl;
    main();
}
```

У меня в текстовом файле имеет 4 студента, и когда я вывожу на экран происходит следующее:

[image: Проблема]

Как видите все нормально показывает, только вот в конце почему то генерирует еще 1 строку где дважды дублируется фамилия предыдущего студента.

---

***Вопрос:*** *Почему он так делает? И каким способом можно это исправить?*

Comment: Классическая ошибка. Цикл с предусловием `!eof` - практически всегда ошибка в С и С++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как видите все нормально показывает, только вот в конце почему то генерирует еще 1 строку где дважды дублируется фамилия предыдущего студента.

Потому что не надо проверять

```
!textfile.eof()
```

На момент проверки конец файла ещё не достигнут - он достигается только при попытке чтения. Соответственно, прочитать ничего не удаётся и в переменной сохраняется предыдущее значение. А ближайшая проверка осуществляется только перед следующей итерацией цикла.

Comment: А как нужно написать?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, как-то так: `for (...; textfile >> line; ...)`.

Comment: тогда выходит что весь цикл я должен перестроить под данное так скажем условие?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, можно ещё `if (!(textfile >> line)) break;`. Но вообще, с условием было бы обычно логичнее.

Comment: Все) Понял ошибку) Спасибо за подсказки :)